# When sortable is dropped fire an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a callback function which fires when a user moves a draggable into a new position ?

So for fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/zyUkd/ 
When "Hello 01" is dragged and dropped into a new area the alert is fired ?

Do I need to use .droppable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

```
$(".selector").draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
       alert('Hello World');
   }
});
```

Or with sortable:

```
$(".selector").sortable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
       alert('Hello World');
   }
});
```

That should do the trick.